# How can i replace the existing mac add with a new mac address using sed

Tags: regex, macos, bash, unix, sed

I have this existing pattern:

```
ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:50:56:bf:71:06"
```

I need to replace a mac address in the above expression with a new mac address using a sed pattern.
Note: The mac-address that needs to replaced is not same everytime.

I tried this sed expression , but no luck..

```
sed 's/ethernet0.generatedAddress.*=.*\"([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}/ethernet0.generatedAddress = \"00:16:3e:5e:1d:01'
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern:

```
([a-z0-9]{2}:[a-z0-9]{2}:[a-z0-9]{2}:[a-z0-9]{2}:[a-z0-9]{2}:[a-z0-9]{2})
```

Or the following one if uppercase letters are used

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2})
```

Replacement:

```
new_mac_address // for instance 00:f6:a0:ff:f1:06
```

Side note: As has been pointer in the comments below, escape parentheses and curly brackets if needed or use `-r` option

Using `sed` it would be something like this (just tested)

```
sed -r 's/(.*)([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2})(.*)/\1\NEW_MAC_ADDRESS\3/g' file.txt
```

Use `-i` option in addition if you want to replace the file on-the-fly

Content of the tested file (file.txt)

```
something before ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:50:56:bf:71:06" and something after
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vQ0oM9/2)

Comment: I think you should include in the regex uppercase characters too. And for `sed` parentheses and curly braces are special, you should escape them.

Comment: @Birei Thanks ;) I wasn't sure if they are used

Comment: It didnt work.

 sed 's/ethernet0.generatedAddress.*=.*\"([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2})/eth
ernet0.generatedAddress = \"00:16:3e:5e:1d:01' mac > temp.junk
sed: unmatched '/'

Comment: @user3363550 What's  that `.*` at the beginning. I didn't add it ;)

Comment: @hex494D49 I removed that .*.. Sed match is failing. :(

Comment: @user3363550 Check out the update; I just tested the command and it works ;)

Comment: @hex494D49yeah the sed pattern works Thanks. The problem is when i put this working sed pattern into a python list and getting some error.

Comment: @user3363550 Hoho ;) even Python came into the game. What's the error? Anyhow, `sed` command is working - at least I answered your question ;)

Comment: sed is absolutely working fine.Thanks Much.
Below is the python error. I have escaped all the backslashes but still,.
>>> mac_li = ['s/ethernet0.generatedAddress.*=.*\"([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2})/ethernet0.generatedAddress =\"{0}/g'.format(mac1)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: @Thanks man! Could you please check out if you sent exactly what is in this command `sed -r 's/(.*)([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2})(.*)/\1\NEW_MAC_ADDRESS\3/g' file.txt` Just a note, this should return a replaced string but it will not replace it in the file; if you want so you should  add -i option to the command. And by the way, what's your Python snippet?

Comment: @hex494D49 SO this what am trying to do.I am trying to replace certain stings in file which is on a remote server.So i am putting all these sed patterns in a list and i iterate over this list and execute sed on the remote server.

when i put the working sed pattern into a list i see a problem,

mac_li = ['s/ethernet0.generatedAddress.*=.*\"([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2})/ethernet0.generatedAddress =\"{0}/g'.format(mac1)]

    raceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59044/discussion-between-user3363550-and-hex494d49).

Comment: @user3363550 I think it's because your format string has three slots, but you are only passing one value. Oh, I'm not a Python master ;) If you can't solve it, please make another question having that Python snippet in, cause I haven't it installed on my server.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `awk`?  It gives simple and easy to understand solution.

```
cat file
some data
ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:50:56:bf:71:06"
more data
```

```
mac="ab:11:23:55:11:cc"
```

```
awk -v m="$mac" -F' "|"' '/ethernet0.generatedAddress/ {$2="\""m"\""}1' file
some data
ethernet0.generatedAddress = "ab:11:23:55:11:cc"
more data
```

It search for `ethernet0.generatedAddress`, if found, replace field `#2` separated by `"` with new mac.

---

If one extra space is not problem, this would be more clean:

```
awk -v m="$mac" -F\" '/ethernet0.generatedAddress/ {$2=FS m FS}1' file
some data
ethernet0.generatedAddress =  "ab:11:23:55:11:cc"
more data
```

Or this:

```
awk -v m="\"$mac\"" -F\" '/ethernet0.generatedAddress/ {$2=m}1' file
```